# CSS selector best practice

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm wasting time on the little things again. The question I'm asking myself - and now YOU - is: what is the "best way" to do CSS selectors/HTML markup?

Do I avoid classes at all cost, leaving the HTML pure and beautiful, or do I add classes whereever I want to style something?

Example, if I want to style the various form buttons of my website, do I go

```
input[type="submit"] { /* styles */ }
```

or do I add a class "form-button" to all of them and do

```
.form-button { /*styles */ }
```

In this trivial example, one might not think too much of it, but if I want to style the third link out of a - semantic, not presentational - list differently, I could make it

```
.navigation ul:nth-of-type(2) a:nth-of-type(3) { /* styles */ }
```

versus just giving that one link a class of "different-link" and use

```
.different-link { /* styles */ }
```

I understand that in 2013, all computing devices and the browsers they run should be quick enough that the technically suboptimal CSS selectors should not make any kind of difference to the end user.

So in the end, it really seems to be a question of 'Do I clutter the HTML (with classes) or do I clutter the CSS (with long-winded selectors)?'

Any opinions on that?

Comment: This is a good question but unfortunately I've had to vote to close it as this will attract primarily opinion-based answers. In CSS there isn't really a best practice - if your styling works then that's brilliant, if it doesn't then you'll need to go back to the drawing board. [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and browser compatibility are things you'll need to consider at all times, and more importantly you'll want your code to be understandable to any future developers who may have to work on it.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: Believe me, there's more to CSS than opinion. :)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik sure but, for instance, claiming that `.form-button` is better than `input[type=submit]` because the markup may change to me is more of an opinion than a fact. You could, after all, simply drop the type selector and just stick with the attribute selector: `[type=submit]`.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: The keyword here is "primarily". You can back your opinions with as many factual references as you want, but at the end of the day, the *premise* of the question is one of subjectivity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Separation of concerns between HTML and CSS

Even though externalised from HTML CSS should be considered separate it's actually not in cases where you insert HTML element-specific selectors. In your case where your selectors relate to actual HTML elements and their hierarchy makes your CSS closely bound to your HTML source. This makes your CSS inflexible and likely larger than it should be.

Hence CSS classes. Whenever you use classes those definitions can be attached to any HTML element as long as they define enough properties. It is true though that your HTML becomes larger due to additional attributes, but semantics doesn't change.

### Why is `.form-button` better than `input[type=submit]` then?

Because you may change your `<input type=submit />` to `<button type=submit>` that is a container and gives much more design freedom to UI designers. If you used CSS classes then you  likely wouldn't change too much about its properties, but if you used tag names, you'd have to overhaul your CSS file and amend it.

Another example would be with other types of inputs i.e. *Cancel* button. In case it was visually identical to *submit* button, designers may say that *Submit* is primary action, and *Cancel* is secondary so it should be displayed as a mere link. Using classes would result in less maintenance again.

### Why classes-only CSS isn't magic bullet either?

Some elements may have specific CSS properties that others don't. Take for example (un)ordered lists. In such cases it does make sense to write tag-based selectors to define CSS style that applies to particular HTML elements. But to avoid selecting all elements of the same type on your page it's suggested to define CSS selector as a combination of tag-based and class-based selector. This makes a so to say **CSS class selector constraint** which makes sense in such cases.

Be advised to separate common style properties with class based selector only and add specific styles to tag+class based selector with constraint as (LESS/SCSS syntax):

```
/* generic */
.navigation {
    background-color: #999;
    margin: 0;

    .item {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
    }
}

/* specific to UL */
ul.navigation {
    list-style: none;
}
```

This gives you the most freedom and improves maintainability to the max.

## Conclusion: Class based selectors are preferred <sup>*hint: OOCSS*</sup>

Yes. Most of the time. This way you'll be able to write object-oriented CSS ([article on SmashingMag](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss), [GitHub repo](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki)) with less code duplication and exceptions. It will improve your CSS maintainability.

> ***Important note:** As with any code you shouldn't over-engineer your CSS either. I've showed you how you can provide flexible style definitions, but you shouldn't always follow these rules. You should provide just enough flexibility at the beginning and refactor as needed while you go. But keep yourself on the classes side most of the time.*

Answer (score 3):

I generally think about coupling.

If you style only using tag names and complex selectors you are tightly coupling you CSS with you HTML. So that if you change just a tiny bit of the markup you'll certainly end up changing also the CSS.
This might be okay for simpler sites, where you have just one or two pages.

For "complex" sites using classes is in my opinion mandatory.
Using classes you can decouple the CSS from the HTML. What I mean is that if you add classes to the main elements of a "thing" (which then becomes a module) you are free to alter the markup, as long as you keep the same classes (obviously, if you change a lot the markup you might need to change a lot also the CSS. For simpler changes like wrapping an element in a `div` or changing an `h1` to an `h2` you won't need to change the CSS).

Also, you CSS becomes easier to read, because when you read this:

```
.blog-posts > .blog-post > .blog-post-title
```

You know you're talking about the style of a title of a blog post, which is way better than

```
div > div > h1
```

(or any other similarly *anonymous* selector).

So if you style smartly with classes, you end up creating modules, which can have simpler selectors, because you don't need to target elements **from the HTML root** element, but from the module root element:

```
.blog-post-title {}
.blog-post-subtitle {}
.blog-post-body {}
.blog-post-tags {}
```

and so on.

[SMACSS](http://smacss.com/) is in my opinion a great way to organise the stylesheets, I suggest you to read about that. As I wrote before, if you are developing a "simple" site, you don't need all this fuss. But for complex sites, having reusable modules is a big plus.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: Depends on what you want.

Explanation:

1) Take this selector `input[type="submit"]`, using this, will target all the submit buttons on your website, you can use this selector when you want to group up/generalize some properties for your buttons, like `font-family`, `font-weight` etc... So using this is not enough, if you are looking to target a particular submit button.

2) Using `.form-button` will target any element having class `.form-button`, so to make it more specific, you can use `input[type=submit].form-button` which will limit the class to be used for only submit buttons. Also, you need to declare class every time you need to style the button.

3) `.navigation ul:nth-of-type(2) a:nth-of-type(3)` This is what I say an over specific selector. It will simply degrade the performance. Not only that, it will also cause you serious specificity issues. You need to use this where you cannot change the markup. Instead of this, calling a `class` on the element you are planning to target will be much more easier as you pointed out in the last point of your question.

---

Conclusion:

`input[type="submit"]` - Use this to group up similar properties which will be shared by all the submit buttons across your website.

`.form-button` - Use this to target buttons you desire to have unique styles(Additional styles you want apart from the properties declared in `input[type=submit]`)

`.navigation ul:nth-of-type(2) a:nth-of-type(3)` - I don't see any reason of using this unless and until you have no other option left but to use this, as it's overspecific for no reason. Again, using it or not depends on some circumstances so can't say completely ignore this.

`.different-link` - Certainly better than using overspecific selectors to style your buttons uniquely.

Answer (score 2):

My Simple line answer to this would be: You should select an element by its tagName not by the class or id if you're giving the same layout throught the website.

The questions make somewhat no sense, as you're making a whole lot of assumptions yourself and are continously answering it too and opinions are not allowed here, you should have asked the question at http://programmers.stackexchange.com. You mentioned

> I understand that in 2013, all computing devices and the browsers they run should be quick enough that the technically suboptimal CSS selectors should not make any kind of difference to the end user.

Then what can be the problem?

The only difference between them is that they will group up the elements with either same tagName or the same class or id. They won't do anything else.

Now its totally upto you to write the code, because on many pages you might want to change the style of the buttons too.

#### Pseudo

Using a pseudo class or selector is a good idea, only when you want to style the childs of a single element, since the submit button has no childs then that selector is vague.

#### Direct selection to the element

```
input[type="submit"] { /* styles */ }
```

This method is the simplest but a better one, this way you style all the input buttons without having to worry about their classes and ids. I myself prefer it.

#### Using ID or Class

```
.form-button { /*styles */ }
```

You might want to use it, when you're styling a button that has to be bigger or smaller, lets say a submit for the checkout button. Which has to be different from other.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not all one or the other.

Your first example of styling a submit `input` with an attribute-based css selector will lead you to override that declaration for the cases where you need a non-standard or different-looking button. So it is probably better to use a very generic CSS declaration in this case and then use classes to add different flavors to your buttons depend on use case.

Look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for example.

I think relying on the CSS cascade is not to be overlooked (in fact it is very useful and powerful) but it is an impractical goal in my experience to try to eliminate classes altogether.